# Data Contract Serialization: using statements

Tags: c#, serialization

I have

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Etc.
{
    [DataContract] public class Email()
    {}
}
```

But Visual Studio is telling me that it cannot resolve the DataContract symbol, and the error message is telling me that the "type DataContractAttribute could not be found" and "has been forwarded to System.Runtime.Serialization; consider adding a reference to that assembly."

As far as I can tell, a reference to that assembly is present, so I am confused as to why the [DataContract] is unresolved. Any suggestions?

Comment: Move your mouse over `DataContract`, wait just a second, and then press `CTRL` + `.`; if it has resolve issues that should show you suggestions.

Comment: weird, it suggested referencing System.Runtime.Serialization (which I already had referenced), and when I pressed Alt + Enter, the library went from grayed out to white.  Guess it works now :)  Thank you.

Comment: No problem man, sometimes Visual Studio gives us all those issues. Often times forcing a build corrects it as well.